# Unit testing of react component with flow types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, flowtype

I am trying to unit test the component below but I am getting the following warning after running `yarn run test`

```
> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) b ut got: object.
```

I'm using here React 16.8 with Flow and Jest and Enzyme as a testing framework

I want to test that component

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'
import Button from './styled'

export type Props = {
  +children: React$Node
}

const ButtonDark = ({ children }: Props) => (
  <>
    <Button>{children}</Button>
  </>
)

export default ButtonDark
```

using this testing file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import ButtonDark from '.'

jest.mock('./styled', () => ({
    Button: 'Button'
}))

describe('ButtonDark', () => {
  it('renders', () => {

    const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonDark>{'some children'}</ButtonDark>)

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Any ideas what can I do to fix it?

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: it's actualy the warning, but there must be something wrong as it never showed up before > Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) b ut got: object.

Comment: but I don't see such an error in sandbox you've provided

Comment: there is no command line in the sandbox, so you can't run yarn run test

Comment: why you mock `./styled`? I guess it's related

Comment: it's not related, if I don't mock it I get the same error

Comment: Are you passing an object as a child somewhere? The error isn't related to Flow at all.